# python setup.py: install either tensorflow or tensorflow-gpu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, setup.py

I'm designing a new project which requires `tensorflow`. As TensorFlow has more than one installation (`tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu`) how do I add to my `install_requires` section that either one is fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's how I worked it out:

```
from pkg_resources import DistributionNotFound, get_distribution
from setuptools import setup, find_packages    

def get_dist(pkgname):
    try:
        return get_distribution(pkgname)
    except DistributionNotFound:
        return None

install_deps = ['numpy', 'tensorflow']
if get_dist('tensorflow') is None and get_dist('tensorflow-gpu') is not None:
    install_deps.remove('tensorflow')

setup(..., install_requires=install_deps)
```